# How can I check if docker compose plugin is installed?

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

I can check if `docker` is installed through the `which docker` or `command -v docker` commands. But I need to check if docker's `compose` plugin is installed (I will use it like `docker compose up -d` later).

Comment: Check that `docker compose version` is giving a successful return. This is actually the command given to check that the plugin was correctly installed in [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/compose-plugin/#install-using-the-repository)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write on terminal:

```
docker compose version
```

The output must look like:

```
Docker Compose version vX.Y.Z
```

Source: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose/

There's an alternative way if it doesn't work.

Write on terminal:

```
  docker-compose --version
```

The return would look like:

```
docker-compose version X.Y.Z, build <identifier>
```

Comment: version instead of --version.

Comment: well, it may depend on the version @AndreyBushman, the OS, etc.
Following the instructions, here's the option --version available: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose/

Comment: Why my answer has negative value without negative comment. Envy? Otherwise write the reason.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked a little bit differently, `docker compose --version` just gave me the CLI options of docker.

```
hotfix@localhost:~$ docker -v
Docker version 23.0.1, build a5ee5b1
hotfix@localhost:~$ docker compose version
Docker Compose version v2.16.0
```

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.01 LTS and I followed [these instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) from Docker for installation.

#### ⚠️ Note

Beware that Docker [is currently transitioning from Compose `v1` to `v2`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-v2/). The older version is called `docker-compose` which version you can check with:

```
docker-compose --version
```

Answer (score 0):

For those trying to check if the `docker compose` is installed using a bash script, you can utilize exit codes to check if the `compose` subcommand of a primary `docker` command returned a "positive" exit code:

```bash
docker compose &>/dev/null # sending output to /dev/null because we don't want it printed

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "INSTALLED"
else
    echo "NOT INSTALLED"
fi
```

Here's a snippet from the script that is used to check for either version of `docker compose` being installed:

```bash
if [ -x "$(command -v docker-compose)" ]; then
    echo "SUCCESS: docker-compose (v1) is installed."
elif $(docker compose &>/dev/null) && [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "SUCCESS: docker compose (v2) is installed."
else
    echo "ERROR: neither \"docker-compose\" nor \"docker compose\" appear to be installed."
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score -2):

You can just check for docker-compose version `docker-compose --version`

If docker-compose is not installed, It will throw an error docker-compose in unrecognized.

Comment: OP is looking for the the existence of the docker compose plugin directly inside the docker cli, not the standalone docker-compose command installed via pip.